# Android 11 October Security Update drastically drains idle battery usage

Tags: battery, battery-life, android-11, doze-mode

**EDIT**
Ever since I installed the latest security patch available for my Phone (October 5 patch), there has been insane idle battery usage. More like 1% dropping sequentially whenever I'm sleeping

*It's worth noting that, this doesn't happen when the phone is in Airplane mode, or switched off*.

I picked up the Paid version of Accu Battery, it doesn't show background battery usage. Better Battery Stats (BBS) was recommended and I went for it but it doesn't work most of the time (shows *No stats have been collected yet*).

But I slept for the past 4 hours and it worked, but I need someone the translate it's output for me, so I can recognize what's draining my battery.

Attached are the screenshots

Model: **TECNO KF7j**

Android Version:  **11**

Device name: **TECNO SPARK 7P**

[image: Accu battery stats]

[image: bbs1]

[image: bbs2]

[image: bbs3]

[image: bbs4]

[image: bbs5]

[image: android settings battery stats]

Comment: At least [edit your post](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/243163/edit) to include make/model of Android device. It would help to know if it is a carrier version for possible bloatware. I would also check for any battery/background restriction settings to see if anything got toggled.

Comment: The dotted gray is the estimated projection that at that time, it's about 4 hours left until it reaches 0%. It's not static and will change depending on the recent usage. You might try [BetterBatteryStats](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-2-2-05-oct-v2-4-betterbatterystats.1179809/) for more detailed info about the battery usage.

Comment: On unrooted devices because of the down-grade protection you can not go back to the old version. Updates on Android can never be uninstalled (unless the update itself was installed as temporary update which is only supported by some newer devices for testing out beta releases which are released as such a temporary update).

Comment: claim it to customer support and wait for next release. or download older ROM and install with SP Flash Tool from PC (you will lose all data)

Comment: Thanks @alecxs, I think this has to be on the manufacturer then. I'll wait for the next security patch. I'm just a month into a 1yr warranty btw. Will the older ROM option void my warranty? Hope it doesn't require root coz I don't have root access

Comment: Thanks @Andrew T. I have tried the Google play paid version of **BetterBatteryStats**, it initially worked well but now it isn't anymore. All I see all day is, *no stats have been collected yet*. AccuBattery on the other hand doesn't show background battery usage